# Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("x", "y", "x_1", "x_2", "y_1", : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent for Panel Data

Tags: r, plm

I encounter the above error while attempting to run the Granger causality test for panel data using the `pgrangertest` function from the `plm` package. I read several questions by users facing a similar issue and tried the suggestions given there, however, none of them could solve my problem.

Essentially, I have a panel data which looks something lime this:

```
>head(granger_data)
       panel_id     time_id close_close_ret log_volume
25-2        25       2     0.004307257       4.753590
25-3        25       3    -0.001912046       8.249836
25-4        25       4     0.011417821       8.628377
25-5        25       5     0.018744691       9.134754
25-6        25       6    -0.024913157       8.920122
25-7        25       7    -0.008604260       8.724370


str(granger_data)
'data.frame':   105209 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ panel_id       : Factor w/ 938 levels "25","26","27",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ time_id        : Factor w/ 323 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ close_close_ret: num  NA 0.00431 -0.00191 0.01142 0.01874 ...
 $ log_volume : num  4.88 4.75 8.25 8.63 9.13 ...
```

Now, I want to run the granger causality test for panel data using the pgrangertest function from the plm package and while doing so, I encounter the following problem:

```
> vol_ret <- pgrangertest(log_volume ~ close_close_ret,data = granger_data)
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("x", "y", "x_1", "y_1")) : 
length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

I even read the source code of the function and tried to understand where the error came, from, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: `plm::pgrangertest` calls `lmtest::grangertest.default` which is where the error is coming from, in the line starting with `colnames(all) <- ` but if you can't give us a dataset that reproduces the error it's hard to help. You could try running `debugonce(lmtest::grangertest.default)` and run your code. Navigate until you get to the line before `colnames(all) <- ` and carefully investigate `all` to see why it might be failing here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked out. The issue was that there was a panel with only a single observation (happened possibly after the NA omission) and so the chisquared values couldn't be computed giving rise to the error since that particular dataframe was shorter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The panel granger test requires to have times series of length 5+3*order per individual otherwise the second order moments of the individual Wald statistics do not exist. `pgrangertest` in package `plm` has a check for that since version 1.7-0 of the package. From its NEWS file:

> - pgrangertest: better detection of infeasibility of test due to lacking data.

It gives an informative error message in case you supply too short a time series for an individual, like in the case you encountered, e.g.:

> Error in pgrangertest(inv ~ value, data = pG, order = 1) :
>   Condition for test = "Ztilde" not met for all individuals: length of
>   time series must be larger than 5+3*order (>5+3*1=8)